# swift4 NSDicitionaryの記述でUse of undeclared type 'NSDicitionary'とエラー表示される

Tags: swift

ref.child("users").child("").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDicitionary　<===
**Use of undeclared type 'NSDicitionary'と表示されます**

```
    let username = value?["username"] as? string ?? ""
    print(username)
```

エラーの解除方法を教えて戴けないでしょうか

Comment: 2箇所に`NSDicitionary`と記載されているので、実際のソースコードにもそのように記載されているのでしょうか。`NSDictionary`だろうと思います。慣れないと見極めが難しいかもしれませんが、`NSDictionary`のように基本的なライブラリに含まれているはずの型名がundeclaredとかundefinedとか表示される場合は、綴りミスかimportが足りないかのどちらかです。よーくお確かめの上でご質問いただいた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: 済みませんでした。綴りミスでした。